# Docker, and small production server infrastructure advices

Tags: nginx, automation, docker, server, docker-compose

I'm figuring out how to setup my production server the best way, but i'm a little bit stuck about how to do it correctly:

Currently, all my web applications are ***dockerified***, i have:

- One nginx front container, that route request to several backend containers:

  - One Symfony App
  - Two Wordpress blog
  - One NodeJS App
- One MySql container for DB storage
- One MongoDB container too

**ALL** this infrastructure is started using ***docker-compose***.

This works fine but it sounds too much **"monolitihic"** for me:

- I cannot stop one container without restarting all the others.
- I cannot add other web applications without restarting everything
- I have no way to restart container automatically after a crash...

This is the first time i'm doing this, do you know some best practices or softwares that can help me to improve my production server ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

> I cannot stop one container without restarting all the others.

What prevents you from using the `docker stop` command instead of the `docker-compose stop` command when you want to stop only one container?

> I cannot add other web applications without restarting everything

I would suggest the use of the excellent [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/blob/master/README.md) nginx docker image to act as a reverse proxy in front of your other containers. This reverse proxy will adapt to the running/stopped containers. You can add a container later on and this reverse proxy will automatically route traffic to it depending on the domain name.

> I have no way to restart container automatically after a crash...

Take a look at the [`restart:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/yml/#working-dir-entrypoint-user-hostname-domainname-mem-limit-privileged-restart-stdin-open-tty-cpu-shares-cpuset-read-only) directive for the *docker-compose.yml* file.

Comment: I already thought about *nginx-proxxy*. I'm actually not using it for the following reason:  
I suppose that the nginx-proxy will NOT serve static assets, so all my applications containers must also embed their own nginx http server.

This sounds great because of the flexibility it brings, but i wonder if it's not overkill ? i.e: if my server is hosting 4 apps, i need to start 5 nginx instances instance of just 1 .... What do you think about that ?

Comment: My view is that nginx-proxy is so easy to install and so easy to maintain (as it is just a matter of playing with the `VIRTUAL_HOST` environment variable) that the overhead is negligible. Also if I have many projects on one server one day, what tells me that I won't need to split those projects on two servers later on? or that one of the project will end before the others? As their lifecycle can be different, I like the idea of having them well separated.

Answer (score 0):

The "monolithic" view of docker-compose is indeed made to allow you to manage your application stack in one way. But one needs to know that docker-compose is a "layer" on top of docker which (docker) you can still use.

As @thomasleveil says, you still can manipulate docker-compose created containers individually with docker.

```
$ docker exec project_web_1 ls -l /
$ docker stop project_db_1
$ docker up -d project_nginx_1
$ ...
```

In another hand I suggest to rely more on docker-compose which also allows to act on individual containers, separate your different applications or environments, and is aware of the dependencies between containers (not being exhaustive).

```
$ docker-compose exec web ls -l /
$ docker-compose stop db
$ docker-compose up -d nginx
$ ...
```

Booting up a new service is also very easy with docker-compose, since it can detect things based on your yml config without stopping anything if not needed.

```
$ docker-compose up -d
project_web_1 is up-to-date
project_db_1 is up-to-date
Creating project_newservice_1
```

I also find the help of a reverse proxy very useful for production installations. However I would more suggest the brand new [Traefik](https://github.com/containous/traefik) which brings nice features like hot-reloading, service discovery, automated SSL certification with Letsencrypt and renewal (not being exhaustive).